# Beanstalkd BackBurner not starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, beanstalkd

Whenever I am starting backburner I get following error but console shows daemon started successfully
/Users/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:214:in `initialize': the scheme beanstalk does not accept registry part: : (or bad hostname?) (URI::InvalidURIError)
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:218:in`new'
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:218:in `parse'
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:747:in`parse'
    from /Users/someuser/application/vendor/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backburner-0.4.6/lib/backburner/connection.rb:46:in `beanstalk_host_and_port'

Comment: Is there some configuration for backburner that might be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you didn't changed a config var.

You should check and see where you have left ``beanstalk_host_and_port`